# magento 1.9 problem custom module programming example problem

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module

I have these files:

**app/code/community/Foggyline/HappyHour/Block/Hello.php**

```
class Foggyline_HappyHour_Block_Hello extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
   public function __construct()
   {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('foggyline_happyhour/hello.phtml');
   }
}

app/code/community/Foggyline/HappyHour/controllers/HelloController.php
class Foggyline_HappyHour_HelloController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
public function helloWorldAction()
{
    //echo 'Hello World #1.';
    $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('foggyline_happyhour/hello');
    //$block->setText('Hello World #2.');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->insert($block);
    $this->renderLayout();      
}
}
```

**app/code/community/Foggyline/HappyHour/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config>
<modules>
    <Foggyline_HappyHour>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </Foggyline_HappyHour>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <foggyline_happyhour>
            <class>Foggyline_HappyHour_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>foggyline_happyhour_resource</resourceModel>
        </foggyline_happyhour>
        <foggyline_happyhour_resource>
            <class>Foggyline_HappyHour_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <user>
                    <table>foggyline_happyhour_user</table>
                </user>
            </entities>
        </foggyline_happyhour_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <foggyline_happyhour_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Foggyline_HappyHour</module>
            </setup>               
        </foggyline_happyhour_setup>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <foggyline_happyhour>
            <class>Foggyline_HappyHour_Block</class>
        </foggyline_happyhour>
    </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <foggyline_happyhour>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Foggyline_HappyHour</module>
                <frontName>happyhour</frontName>
            </args>
        </foggyline_happyhour>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
<!-- ... other elements ... -->
</config>
```

**app/code/community/Foggyline/HappyHour/Model/User.php**

```
class Foggyline_HappyHour_Model_User extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
  protected $_eventPrefix = 'foggyline_happyhour_user';
  protected $_eventObject = 'user';
  protected function _construct()
  {
    $this->_init('foggyline_happyhour/user');
  }
}
```

**app/code/community/Foggyline/HappyHour/Model/Resource/User.php**

```
class Foggyline_HappyHour_Model_Resource_User extends 
      Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
   protected function _construct()
   {
    $this->_init('foggyline_happyhour/user', 'user_id');
   } 
}
```

**app/code/community/Foggyline/HappyHour/Model/Resource/User/Collection.php**

```
  class Foggyline_HappyHour_Model_Resource_User_Collection extends 
  Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
 {
    public function _construct()
   {
    $this->_init('foggyline_happyhour/user');
   }
 }
```

app/code/community/Foggyline/HappyHour/sql/foggyline_happyhour_setup/install-1.0.0.0.php

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable($installer- 
>getTable('foggyline_happyhour/user'))->addColumn('user_id', 
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
'identity' => true,
'unsigned' => true,
'nullable' => false,
'primary' => true,), 'Id')->addColumn('firstname', 
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null,
array(
  'nullable' => false,
 ), 'User first name')->addColumn('lastname', 
 Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null,
 array(
 'nullable' => false,
  ), 'User last name')->setComment('Foggyline_HappyHour User Entity');
 $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
 $installer->endSetup();
```

**app/etc/modules/Foggyline_HappyHour.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
     <Foggyline_HappyHour>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
     </Foggyline_HappyHour>
   </modules>
 </config>
```

The problem is when I load a page the `install-1.0.0.0.php` script run and it creates a row into the `core_resource` table with these values:

```
| foggyline_happyhour_setup  | 0.1.1      | 0.1.1        |
```

The table `foggyline_happyhour_user` is not been created.
I can't figure out what is the problem.

Comment: This mean that your module is well passed but it doesn't create your table, because there is some error in your install script !

Answer (score 0):

Here problem with your setup file name and module version. In config.xml you declare **1.0.0.0** but in core_resource table it is **0.1.1**.

So delete row **foggyline_happyhour_setup  | 0.1.1      | 0.1.1** from core_resource table.

Clear cache and run again.

Comment: Wait ... :) He has written that the install script creates these entries.